# How to call an object's method from a selector (from a string) and get the returning value of that method (no matter what type is)?

Tags: objective-c, methods, selector, return-value

Ok, here's what I have:

```
SEL propertySelector = NSSelectorFromString(keyPath);
if ([obj respondsToSelector:propertySelector]){
    id propertyValue = [obj performSelector:propertySelector];
}
```

So, the `keyPath` is a `NSString` and it's used to pass the string name of a method. After that, I create a `@selector` from that string using `NSSelectorFromString()` and I check if the object (`obj`) responds to that selector.
But now here's the problem, I want to get the returning value of the method that I want to call, but it seems like the code above doesn't work with type values like `int`, `NSInteger`, etc.. because I'm using `id` for the `propertyValue` (if I call the method above in the middle of another method, and the `keyPath` is referencing a method that returns an int, the first method will stop being executed).
How can I receive the value of the method no matter what type it is?
Thanks!

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What happens? Do you get an error (what's the error)? Is `propertyValue` `nil` or some other unexpected value?

Comment: I've just updated my question. See if it's better now. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this kind of dynamism is a strong ***code smell***.  Objective-C is not designed to be this kind of a loose, introspection heavy, untyped language.   There is very likely to be a much more straightforward way of doing what you want.  Might require a few more lines of code, but the end result will be far more maintainable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're accessing a property, you should definitely consider KVC, which boxes up the primitive into an `NSNumber` for you.

```
NSInteger val = [[obj valueForKeyPath:keyPath] integerValue];
```

As for your literal question, the [`performSelector:` docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCBGHFG) tell you what to do.

> For methods that return anything other than an object, use [`NSInvocation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSInvocation).

Which looks like this:

```
NSInteger retVal;
SEL sel = NSSelectorFromString(keyPath);
NSMethodSignature * sig = [obj methodSignatureForSelector:sel];
NSInvocation * inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
[inv setTarget:obj];
[inv setSelector:sel];
[inv invoke];
[inv getReturnValue:&retVal];

// Use retVal
```

Comment: Note that NSInvocation won't work "no matter what", because there are types that NSInvocation is unable to handle. This should work for Objective-C objects, simple scalar types, and simple structs. It won't work for non-POD C++ types or some complicated structs.

Comment: Good info, thanks, @GregParker. Would that failure be in the form of an exception, or something subtle?

Comment: Could be an exception from NSInvocation, or a crash, or something subtle.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what you're doing, you can use `objc_msgSend` directly:

```
NSInteger (*f)(id, SEL) = (NSInteger (*)(id, SEL))objc_msgSend;
SEL propertySelector = NSSelectorFromString(keyPath);
if ([obj respondsToSelector:propertySelector]){
    NSInteger retVal = f(obj, propertySelector);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works like a charm for me:

```
- (void)foo {
    SEL propertySelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"doSomething");
    if ([self respondsToSelector:propertySelector]){
        id propertyValue = [self performSelector:propertySelector];
        NSLog(@"%@", propertyValue);
    }
}

- (NSNumber *)doSomething {
    return @42;
}
```

Output is, as expected:

> 42

There could eventually be a problem if you method return type is not an object (and this seems to be the case based on your edit). From the doc:

> **performSelector:**
>
> Sends a specified message to the receiver and returns the result of the message. (required)
>
> **Return Value**
>
> An *object* that is the result of the message.

*(emphasis on **object**)*.

If you try to use `performSelector:` on a selector which return type is not a object, you will get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Which means you must change your return type and encapsulate the returned value in an object (eg. `NSNumber` or `NSValue`). Note that in the case of an `int` or `NSInteger` or other "number" types, this can be done by enclosing the value with `@()` (for example `return 3.2;` becomes `return @(3.2);`).