# How to completely hide the Xcode warning "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'id' to parameter of type (...)"?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, warnings, primitive-types

I have a method in my class that receives a `@selector` and an object (`id`), and that particular method returns an `id` (which is the returning value after I performed the `@selector` on the object I received).
So, here's what I have for the `return` of my method (this is only one line, I have a line for each primitive type: int, short, long, etc...):

```
return [NSNumber numberWithChar:[obj performSelector:sel]];
```

And Xcode gives me this warning, which is a very good point:

> Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'id' to parameter
>   of type 'char'

But, the thing is, before I execute the `return` above with the according `NSNumber`'s `-numberWith...`, I make sure that the type of the value returned by `[obj performSelector:sel]` is the correct one, so I want to hide the Xcode's warning because it doesn't help me with anything.

I've tried `[NSNumber numberWithChar:[[obj performSelector:sel] charValue]]` to work around the warning (this made the warning go away) but my program crashes now, with that new `charValue`.


Any ideas on how to hide the error (no matter of what type is) or how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned in your last question, `performSelector:` can't be used to get a primitive return type. You should not turn off the warning. Assuming that the method named by the selector returns a `char`, your fix is correct. Why does it crash?

Comment: What is the actual return type of the selector you are calling?

Comment: Notice that you're getting the same advice here as in your previous question [How to call an objects method from a selector from a string and get the retur?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20306356)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call an object's method from a selector (from a string) and get the returning value of that method (no matter what type is)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306356/how-to-call-an-objects-method-from-a-selector-from-a-string-and-get-the-retur)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the general fix is to use an explicit message send instead of `performSelector:`, because `performSelector:` expects the method to return an object and won't always work correctly when the method returns something else. So you want `return [NSNumber numberWithChar:[obj whateverSelContains]]`.

However, you can probably use Key-Value Coding as a substitute for `performSelector:` here. It's hard to say without seeing your real code, but assuming this is a no-argument method that returns a char, that approach should work. In that case, you'll want a string instead of a SEL. Then you can do `[[obj valueForKey:whateverWasInSel] charValue]` and that will work.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for `performSelector:` contains the answer:

> For methods that return anything other than an object, use `NSInvocation`.

Values of different types may be returned differently (using different registers, on the stack, etc.). What you are trying to do is take a selector defined to return an `id` and treat the result as though it is some other (primitive) type. It *may* work, but it is **not** guaranteed or required to work.

So don't hide try to hide the error, fix your code!

Answer (score 1):

you seriously don't want to ignore these warnings. In the event that they are actually invalid you should be using a C cast to 'hide' the warning.

***If*** this is one of those cases then do this:

```
return [NSNumber numberWithChar:(char)[obj performSelector:sel]];
```

I don't know that `performSelector:` will return a non object, I'm pretty sure the docs say to use `NSInvocation` for such cases, but I cannot find it ATM, will update if I do.

Edit: [The docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html) indeed say to use `NSInvocation` for methods that don't return an objective-c object.

Comment: This is not a good habit to get into with `performSelector:`: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/288663-bool-returned-via-performselctor-not-bool-on-64-bit-system.html#288689